# Attach help to error in error list

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, envdte

I am developing Visual studio plugin.

In plug in , I am adding error in error list of visual studio plug in.

I know how to add error. Now I want to give help for each error.

I am using below code to add error to error list :

```
public static ErrorListProvider errorListProvider;
var newError = new ErrorTask();
        newError.ErrorCategory = errorCategory;
        newError.Category = TaskCategory.BuildCompile;
        newError.Text = errorMsg;
        newError.Document = errorDoc;
        newError.Line = line;
errorListProvider.Tasks.Add(newError);
```

So how to attach **Help** to each error in error list?

**Note:** When user right click on error. It menu has "Show error Help" option. 
I want to give help on that option.

Comment: Derive your own class from ErrorTask so you can override its OnHelp() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach eventhandler to *Help* event of ErrorTask.

```
newError.Help += new EventHandler(Showhelp);
```

Put your code in below eventhandler method

```
static void Showhelp(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        // Put your code here
}
```